# How to convert tuple to dictionary while maintaining same order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I have sorted that dictionary by values. Following is code with sample data:

```
mydict = {'b':4, 'a':1, 'd':8, 'c':10}
```

Now, I want to sort this by value in descending order and hence, I used the following code:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

When I print sorted_dict, I get a list of tuples:

```
sorted_dict
[('c', 10), ('d', 8), ('b', 4), ('a', 1)]
```

However, I want this in the form of dictionary. So I used the following code:

```
dict(sorted_dict)
```

and got the following result:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 10, 'b': 4, 'd': 8}
```

So, it looks like dict() method is automatically sorting dictionary by key. However, my desired output is:

```
{'c':10, 'd':8, 'b':4, 'a':1}
```

How do I obtain this output?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

You can’t with a regular `dict`, which is not an ordered collection to begin with. `collections.OrderedDict`, however, is!

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict([('c', 10), ('d', 8), ('b', 4), ('a', 1)])
>>> d
OrderedDict([('c', 10), ('d', 8), ('b', 4), ('a', 1)])
```

Granted, the output doesn’t look very meaningful, but it is correct. You can access items by key and iterate through pairs in order.